# Visual Studio 2017 freezes when opening Xamarin .axml files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin

I want to start developing .net Xamarin applications, but my VS keeps freezing when I try to open the layout files for the project, I have the latest version of VS installed and the Xamarin tools as well.

I have to use the task manager to close VS and I cannot develop at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same, after a visual studio update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved in version 15.7.4,
[Bug Link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/266846/axml-file-doesnt-open.html)

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED** at the bottom (edit 2) more info

It's an issue with version 15.7.3 (to check your version go to `Help` -> `About Microsoft Visual Studio`) and [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1777) is its page on github, I have the same problem too and apparantly many others, you can report it by going to `Help` -> `Send Feedback` -> `Report a problem` -> `Report new problem`, [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/visual+studio+2017+version+15.7.3.html) is another link talking about it.

Sorry I made this an answer but I'm not allowed to comment (reputation < 50)

**EDIT**: according to the [previous](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1777#issuecomment-394967463) link they're in their final steps of fixing it, and a workaround for now as I have been told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50714377/6877477)

> For now, here are some workaround:
>
> - If you need to open a .axml file in VS 15.7.3, you could change its extension name to .xml then open it.
>
> Or:
>
> - Right-click the .axml file then use "open with" --> eg: choose XML Editor

**EDIT 2**: it was finally fixed [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1777#issuecomment-395081355) you can download it and everything finally works as expected